# Problem with perfectly balanced tree with fixed size

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, binary-search-tree

I tried to implement a perfectly balanced binary search tree, where the size is given as a type parameter (like C++'s `std::array` does).

This is the implementation of the tree:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Foldable hiding (length)
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Proxy


data MultiSet (n :: Nat) a where
    Leaf :: MultiSet 0 a
    Odd :: MultiSet n a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet (n+n+1) a
    Even :: MultiSet n a -> a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet (n+n+2) a
```

And this is the implementation of `minView`, as similar as `Data.Set` from `containers` package:

```
minView :: MultiSet (n+1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a) 
minView (Odd Leaf x Leaf) = (x, Leaf)
minView (Even Leaf x y Leaf) = (x, Odd Leaf y Leaf)
minView (Odd l x r) = let
    (u, l') = minView l
    (v, r') = minView r
    in (u, Even l' x v r')
minView (Even l x y r) = let
    (u, l') = minView l
    in (u, Odd (insert x l') y r)
```

But many errors occur when I try to interpret it:

```
PerfectBalance.hs:71:33: error:
    • Could not deduce: n ~ 0
    from the context: (n + 1) ~ ((n5 + n5) + 1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Odd :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                        MultiSet n a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 1) a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:71:10-24
    or from: n5 ~ 0
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Leaf :: forall a. MultiSet 0 a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:71:14-17
    ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
        minView :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                    MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        at PerfectBalance.hs:70:1-48
    Expected type: MultiSet n a
        Actual type: MultiSet 0 a
    • In the expression: Leaf
    In the expression: (x, Leaf)
    In an equation for ‘minView’: minView (Odd Leaf x Leaf) = (x, Leaf)
    • Relevant bindings include
        minView :: MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:71:1)
|
71 | minView (Odd Leaf x Leaf) = (x, Leaf)
|                                 ^^^^

PerfectBalance.hs:72:36: error:
    • Could not deduce: n ~ 1
    from the context: (n + 1) ~ ((n5 + n5) + 2)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Even :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                        MultiSet n a -> a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 2) a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:72:10-27
    or from: n5 ~ 0
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Leaf :: forall a. MultiSet 0 a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:72:15-18
    ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
        minView :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                    MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        at PerfectBalance.hs:70:1-48
    Expected type: MultiSet n a
        Actual type: MultiSet ((0 + 0) + 1) a
    • In the expression: Odd Leaf y Leaf
    In the expression: (x, Odd Leaf y Leaf)
    In an equation for ‘minView’:
        minView (Even Leaf x y Leaf) = (x, Odd Leaf y Leaf)
    • Relevant bindings include
        minView :: MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:71:1)
|
72 | minView (Even Leaf x y Leaf) = (x, Odd Leaf y Leaf)
|                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PerfectBalance.hs:75:23: error:
    • Could not deduce: (n2 + 1) ~ n5
    from the context: (n + 1) ~ ((n5 + n5) + 1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Odd :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                        MultiSet n a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 1) a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:73:10-18
    ‘n5’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
        Odd :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                MultiSet n a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 1) a,
        in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:73:10-18
    Expected type: MultiSet (n2 + 1) a
        Actual type: MultiSet n5 a
    • In the first argument of ‘minView’, namely ‘r’
    In the expression: minView r
    In a pattern binding: (v, r') = minView r
    • Relevant bindings include
        r' :: MultiSet n2 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:75:9)
        r :: MultiSet n5 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:73:18)
        l :: MultiSet n5 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:73:14)
|
75 |     (v, r') = minView r
|                       ^

PerfectBalance.hs:76:12: error:
    • Could not deduce: ((n2 + n2) + 2) ~ n
    from the context: (n + 1) ~ ((n5 + n5) + 1)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Odd :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                        MultiSet n a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 1) a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:73:10-18
    ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
        minView :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                    MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        at PerfectBalance.hs:70:1-48
    Expected type: MultiSet n a
        Actual type: MultiSet ((n2 + n2) + 2) a
    • In the expression: Even l' x v r'
    In the expression: (u, Even l' x v r')
    In the expression:
        let
        (u, l') = minView l
        (v, r') = minView r
        in (u, Even l' x v r')
    • Relevant bindings include
        l' :: MultiSet n2 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:74:9)
        r' :: MultiSet n2 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:75:9)
        minView :: MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:71:1)
|
76 |     in (u, Even l' x v r')
|            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

PerfectBalance.hs:78:23: error:
    • Could not deduce: (n3 + 1) ~ n5
    from the context: (n + 1) ~ ((n5 + n5) + 2)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Even :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                        MultiSet n a -> a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 2) a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:77:10-21
    ‘n5’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        a pattern with constructor:
        Even :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                MultiSet n a -> a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 2) a,
        in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:77:10-21
    Expected type: MultiSet (n3 + 1) a
        Actual type: MultiSet n5 a
    • In the first argument of ‘minView’, namely ‘l’
    In the expression: minView l
    In a pattern binding: (u, l') = minView l
    • Relevant bindings include
        l' :: MultiSet n3 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:78:9)
        r :: MultiSet n5 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:77:21)
        l :: MultiSet n5 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:77:15)
|
78 |     (u, l') = minView l
|                       ^

PerfectBalance.hs:79:12: error:
    • Could not deduce: ((n5 + n5) + 1) ~ n
    from the context: (n + 1) ~ ((n5 + n5) + 2)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                Even :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                        MultiSet n a -> a -> a -> MultiSet n a -> MultiSet ((n + n) + 2) a,
                in an equation for ‘minView’
        at PerfectBalance.hs:77:10-21
    ‘n’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
        minView :: forall (n :: Nat) a.
                    MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        at PerfectBalance.hs:70:1-48
    Expected type: MultiSet n a
        Actual type: MultiSet ((n5 + n5) + 1) a
    • In the expression: Odd (insert x l') y r
    In the expression: (u, Odd (insert x l') y r)
    In the expression:
        let (u, l') = minView l in (u, Odd (insert x l') y r)
    • Relevant bindings include
        r :: MultiSet n5 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:77:21)
        l :: MultiSet n5 a (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:77:15)
        minView :: MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
        (bound at PerfectBalance.hs:71:1)
|
79 |     in (u, Odd (insert x l') y r)
|            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`maxView`, `insert`, and `delete` also have similar problems.

How can I resolve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHC does not know algebra. *Any* algebra. Things like `n + 1 /= 0` and `n + 1 = m + 1 -> n = m` are beyond it. The best it can do is evaluation, such as `1 + 1 = 2`. You have to explicitly write them down as axioms, implement them with `unsafeCoerce`, and tell GHC to use them. (Or, you can use a compiler plugin to hook GHC to a solver that *can* do algebra and translate those results into axioms.)

Also, even if GHC could do algebra, in the `Odd l x r` and `Even l x y r` cases, `l, r :: MultiSet m a` where it is *not known* that `m = m' + 1`. That is, even though you have already matched `l` and `r` against `Leaf`, and therefore "proved" that `l` and `r` contain more than one element, this is not proven to GHC. Roughly, the reasoning behind "`l` and `r` are non-empty" is not "direct" enough. Failed matches do not give you more type information about the scrutinee. I would write a helper function:

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, ExplicitForAll, ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications #-}
import Data.Proxy
import Data.Type.Equality
import Data.Void
import Unsafe.Coerce

data NatCheck (n :: Nat) where
  IsZero :: NatCheck 0
  IsSucc :: Proxy n -> NatCheck (n + 1)
  -- Proxy lets us bind the predecessor to a name
checkMultiSet :: forall n a. MultiSet n a -> NatCheck n
checkMultiSet Leaf = IsZero
checkMultiSet (Odd _ _ _) = IsSucc Proxy
-- get m :: Nat out of Even, learn n = (m + m) + (1 + 1) from it
-- reassociate: n = ((m + m) + 1) + 1
checkMultiSet (Even (_ :: MultiSet m a) _ _ _) | Refl <- addAssoc @(m + m) @1 @1 = IsSucc Proxy

-- axiom
addAssoc :: forall n m l. ((n + m) + l) :~: (n + (m + l))
addAssoc = unsafeCoerce Refl
```

And use that instead of explicitly using the constructors of `MultiSet`

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
minView :: forall n a. MultiSet (n + 1) a -> (a, MultiSet n a)
minView Leaf = case natDiscrim @n Refl of { } -- Leaf is not ruled out automatically, have to prove unreachability with axiom n + 1 /= 0
minView (Odd l x r) = -- get m :: Nat, learn n + 1 = m + m + 1, get l, r of size m
  case checkMultiSet l of -- i.e. check m =? 0
    -- learn m = 0, so n + 1 = 0 + 1
    -- injectivity: n = 0
    IsZero | Refl <- succInj @n @0 -> (x, Leaf) 
    -- get m' :: Nat, learn m = m' + 1
    -- get l', r' of size m'
    -- we know n + 1 = (m' + 1) + (m' + 1) + 1
    -- the Even has size ((m' + m') + 2) when it should be n
    -- algebra, except more painfully than ever before
    -- injectivity gets: n = (m' + 1) + (m' + 1)
    -- reassociate: n = ((m' + 1) + m') + 1
    -- commute: n = (m' + (m' + 1)) + 1
    -- reassociate: n = ((m' + m') + 1) + 1
    -- reassociate: n = (m' + m') + (1 + 1)
    IsSucc (Proxy :: Proxy m')
      | (u, l') <- minView l, (v, r') <- minView r
      , Refl <- succInj @n @((m' + 1) + (m' + 1))
      , Refl <- addAssoc @(m' + 1) @m' @1
      , Refl <- addComm @(m' + 1) @m'
      , Refl <- addAssoc @m' @m' @1
      , Refl <- addAssoc @(m' + m') @1 @1
      -> (u, Even l' x v r')
minView (Even (l :: MultiSet m a) x y r) = -- get m :: Nat, learn n + 1 = m + m + 2, get l, r of size m
  case checkMultiSet l of -- i.e. check m =? 0
    -- learn m = 0, so n + 1 = 1 + 1
    -- injectivity: n = 1
    IsZero | Refl <- succInj @n @1 -> (x, Odd Leaf y Leaf)
    -- get m' :: Nat, learn m = m' + 1, get l' of size m'
    -- we know n + 1 = (m + m) + (1 + 1)
    -- the Odd has size ((m + m) + 1) when it should be n
    -- algebra, less painful
    -- reassociate: n + 1 = ((m + m) + 1) + 1
    -- injectivity: n = (m + m) + 1
    IsSucc _
      | (u, l') <- minView l
      , Refl <- addAssoc @(m + m) @1 @1
      , Refl <- succInj @n @(m + m + 1)
      -> (u, Odd (insert x l') y r)

-- more axioms
natDiscrim :: forall n. (n + 1) :~: 0 -> Void
natDiscrim Refl = error "natDiscrim: impossible"
succInj :: forall n m. (n + 1) ~ (m + 1) => n :~: m
succInj = unsafeCoerce Refl
addComm :: forall n m. (n + m) :~: (m + n)
addComm = unsafeCoerce Refl
```

Of course, instead of explaining the algebra to GHC, you could just brute force it by e.g. replacing the block of guards in the `Odd`, `IsSucc` case with `Refl <- unsafeCoerce Refl :: n ~ (m' + m' + 2)`, and similarly for the others. I wouldn't do that though, since it's not obvious that that is correct. In contrast, the axioms are obviously correct. By doing your algebra in terms of them, you prove your reasoning correct, too.

Comment: Mama mia! I *hate* `unsafeCoerce`, as a normal Haskellian would do. Yet there doesn't seem a workaround in this case.